# Adding two lists to selectize, the first one should be selected by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Hi I've a litle problem with selectize, namely how to add two lists and he first one should be selected by default and enduser can select items from second list in same form. Below you can find my code. If I add two times options selectize takes second one only).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    lol = "lol1 , lol2 , lol3"
    var lol = lol.split(',');
    var lol = lol.map(function(x) { return { item: x}; });
    console.log(lol)
    console.log(typeof(lol))

    wtf = "wtf1 , wtf2 , wtf3"
    var wtf = wtf.split(',');
    var wtf = wtf.map(function(x) { return { item: x}; });
    console.log(wtf)
    console.log(typeof(wtf))

     $('#show_tags').selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button', 'restore_on_backspace'],
        select: true,
        delimiter: ',',
        maxItems: null,
        options: lol,
        options: wtf,
        labelField: 'item',
        valueField: 'item',
        searchField: 'item',
        create: true
    });
});
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `items` to provide an array of values for the options that should be selected by default (instead of using two `options` arrays). Option values are determined by your `valueField` setting.

For example:

```
$('#select-id').selectize({
  items: ['1', '2'], // preselected options values
  options: [
    { value: '1', name: 'Item 1' }, // this option will be preselected
    { value: '2', name: 'Item 2' }, // this option will be preselected
    { value: '3', name: 'Item 3' },
    { value: '4', name: 'Item 4' }
  ],
  valueField: 'value',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: ['name'],
  delimiter: ',',
  select: true,
  create: true,
  maxItems: null
});
```