# How to close the list of options in a selectize.js select-list?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have a selectized.js multi-select-list which is created with all of the options that the user is to select from.  I used the following commands to programmatically select each option that were stored in a database, but besides selecting options, the list of options is displayed:

```
// Create a variable that 'points' to the listSelect selelect list that
// has been converted to a selectize list.  The list already has all of the
// options in it.

$listSelectize = $( '#listSelect' );

// Clear all previously selected options ...

$listSelectize[ 0 ].selectize.clear( true ); // Clear previous selections.

// Select each list option that was saved in the database ...

// This is a test example ...

$listSelectize[ 0 ].selectize.addItem( 'option_one', true );

// The above command correctly select the option with the 'option_one' value,
// but it also causes the option list drop-down to be displayed.

// I've tried using the following commands to close the option list, but the
// drop-down list remains open.

$listSelectize[ 0 ].selectize.close();

// I've noticed that if after the form becomes interactive, that I can click
// it and the list closes, so the next few commands try to simulate this
// programmatically, but the list remains open, anyway.

$listSelectize[ 0 ].selectize.blur();  // Documentation says this should
                                       // force the focus away from the list.

$listSelectize[ 0 ].blur();            // This should do the same.

document.getElementById( 'firstInput' ).focus();
```

Is there a way to select the opens without opening the option drop-down list?

If not, how can I close it so the user doesn't see it when the form becomes usable?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell from your code sample why your select menu is staying open. See working snippet below where a select option is automatically selected but the select menu is not opened. Also added a couple of buttons to trigger the selectize `open()` and `close()` functions so that you can test those as well. You may need to check for conflicting jquery, js, or css that is not included in your question to find the source of your issue.

```js
const options = [
  { id: 1, name: "option1" },
  { id: 2, name: "option2" },
  { id: 3, name: "option3" }
];
  
const select = $('#select1').selectize({
  options: options,
  valueField: 'name',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: ['name'],
  persist: false,
  create: true
});

const openBtn = document.querySelector('#open');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close');
openBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  select[0].selectize.open();
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  select[0].selectize.close();
});

select[0].selectize.addItem('option2');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Selectize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="open">Open</button>
    <button id="close" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Close</button>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input id="select1" name="select1" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  I put it in a CodePen and am adding my custom code to see which part of my code is causing the problem.

Comment: Would you happen to know how I might be able to use the load method to select items in the options list without dumping the options?  The list of options to select is already on the browser client-side, so an ajax call isn't needed.

Comment: Are you just trying to default select certain options when the select is first displayed? If so, see [this example code for default selection of selectize options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672716/adding-two-lists-to-selectize-the-first-one-should-be-selected-by-default/50959585#50959585).

Comment: No, the list I'm creating contains music categories that the user may chose one or more of to populate a field in a record that is then stored in a database.  The user may later modify this record, including the music categories.  The list now contains about 360 categories and groups of categories, such as Rock and Country.  I use selectize on an html <select> element with <optgroup> and <option> elements.  However, because the list is so big, I don't want to destroy and recreate the list. Rather, I want to clear the selected items and reselect the previously saved items in the database.

Comment: Your solution, if I understand it would require that I recreate the list each time a record is created or edited, which I really don't want to do.  My hope is to create a selectized list with all of the options and option-groups and event handling code in place.  Then when a user creates/edits a record, I clear any previously selected option items, select saved items in the case of editing, and then display the list in my form.

Comment: After looking at the code you posted in your answer and then in the example code for default selection of selectized options, I can see besides creating the list and selected items from arrays rather than <select>, <optgroup>, and <option> elements, that these solutions don't seem to handle the reselection of items, but rather need to destroy and recreate the entire list.  That's why I asked about using the load method, which might be able to reselect one more options in the <select> list's <options> and add new options, too, as the user might add new options to the list.

Comment: Note, when the page is first loaded, it contains all of the user's records, and previously selected music categories in each record, therefore I only need to create the <select>, <optgroup>, <option> list when the pate is first loaded and convert it to a selectize list once.  When the user creates a new record, I save the data to the database with an ajax call and in a new row in a table where there is a row for each record.  When the  user edits an existed record, I update the data in the database with an ajax call and replace the data in the table row for that record.

Comment: By the way, I was able to reproduce the problem I reported in this question using the code in your first answer -- the list of options opens and remains open when options are selected using addItem method.  Unfortunately, I'm still looking into why this is happening.

Comment: You don't need to recreate the options list each time a user creates or updates their personal list of preferred categories (the `load` method does create the option list when you initialize the selectize control, so not sure that is what you want on update). When the page loads and on subsequent updates, why don't you just loop through the user selected options and use `select[0].selectize.addItem(item)` to populate the field with the updated options (and `select[0].selectize.clear()` beforehand if it is an update after the page has already loaded)?

Comment: Also, if you can recreate the issue of the selectize control "sticking" open in a snippet in your question (or in a fiddle or pen), then we might be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: Thank you for responding again.  I'll stand up my selection list in CodePen.  I was using the select[0].selectize.clear() and select[0].selectize.addItem(...) as you suggest.  That's when I found that the list was 'sticking' open.

Comment: Here is the CodePen demo url: https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/aazWwY  When you open the page the list is populated with demo data and an alert is displayed indicating that the list will open after you press the OK button.  You can scroll down to the code that initializes the list with demo data by searching for '// ===================================='.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the `itemAdd` function you are calling from the `onItemAdd` method when initializing the selectize control. That function calls both `refreshItems()` and `refreshOptions()` both of which set focus to the control and cause it to open. If you comment out the `onItemAdd` method, you will see what I mean. I only took a quick look but I am not sure you need that method at all.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this!  Good catch.  The itemAdd event handler adds delete item click handler to the new items that a user adds to the list and it scrolls the newly added items into view, both of which are only needed after the list becomes interactive. So, I can block the refreshes when doing a silent addItem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Bravo to benvc.  Your observation about the refreshItmes() and refreshOptions() method calls in the onItemAdd itemAdd function were spot-on.  As I indicated in my last comment, I added an interactive variable and set it to false when I expected to 'silently' reset the items in the selectize list and then set interactive to true when finished with the reset.  Then I added an if statement that enclosed the refresh calls and the list scrolling in the itemAdd function, so that these statements only execute when the value of interactive is true.

Thanks again!